# PySide QML Charts update Series with real-time data

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside2

I tried to update the chart series dynamically with new data recieved using OPC UA Protocol

**Python Code:**

```
class Thread(QThread):

    motor1 = Signal(int)
    motor2 = Signal(int)
    motor3 = Signal(int)
    var = Signal(int)
    strr = Signal(str)

    def run(self):
        client.connect()

        while True:
            d1 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_1")
            d2 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_2")
            d3 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_3")
            button = client.get_node("ns=4;s=QT_Button")
            string = client.get_node("ns=4;s=QT_String")
            button = button.get_value()
            string = string.get_value()
            d1 = d1.get_value()
            d2 = d2.get_value()
            d3 = d3.get_value()
            self.motor1.emit(d1)
            self.motor2.emit(d2)
            self.motor3.emit(d3)
            self.var.emit(d1)
            self.strr.emit(string)


    class ChartModel(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChartModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.var.connect(self.opcua)
        self.thread.start()
        self.timestamp = time()
        self.my_data = []

        self.my_list = []

        self.index = -1

    @Slot(QtCharts.QAbstractSeries)
    def update_series(self, series):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index > 4:
            self.index = 0
        series.clear()

        for p in self.my_data[self.index]:
            series.append(p.x(), p.y())

    @Slot()
    def generateData(self):

        for i in range(5):

            my_list = []
            for j in range(500):
                my_list.append(QPoint(j, random.uniform(1, 70)))

            self.my_data.append(my_list)

    @Slot(int)
    def opcua(self, val):
        tsignal = time() - self.timestamp
        XY = QPoint(tsignal, val)
        self.my_list.append(XY)

    @Slot()
    def get_data(self):
        self.my_data.append(self.my_list)
        print(len(self.my_data))


    class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    chartmodel = ChartModel()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    # engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("chartmodel", chartmodel)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**QML Code**

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1


Item {
   width: 1000
   height: 800


    Rectangle {
         id: rectangle
          property int amountOfData: 0
          color: "#27273a"
          anchors.fill: parent
       Timer{
            id: miTimer
            interval: 100
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {

                 chartmodel.update_series(chartViewItem.series(0))




        }
    }
    MessageDialog {
        id: msgbox
        title: "Error"
        text: "Data are not accepted !"
        onAccepted: {
            msgbox.close();


        }
        Component.onCompleted: visible = false
    }

    ChartView {
        id: chartViewItem
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 752
        height: 592
        antialiasing: true
        theme:ChartView.ChartThemeDark
        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min:0
            max:500

         }

        ValueAxis{
            id: axisY
            min:0
            max:100
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: horizontalScrollMask
            visible: false
            anchors.fill: parent
        }

        MouseArea {
            id: chartMouseAreaA
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.rightMargin: -8
            anchors.bottomMargin: -8
            anchors.leftMargin: 8
            anchors.topMargin: 8

            acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

            onMouseXChanged: {
                if ((mouse.buttons & Qt.LeftButton) == Qt.LeftButton) {
                    chartViewItem.scrollLeft(mouseX - horizontalScrollMask.x);


                    horizontalScrollMask.x = mouseX;
                }
            }
            onPressed: {
                if (mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) {
                    horizontalScrollMask.x = mouseX;
                }
            }




        }


    }

    TextField {
        id: mintxt
        x: 766
        y: 68
        placeholderText: qsTr("min X")
    }

    TextField {
        id: maxtxt
        x: 766
        y: 124
        placeholderText: qsTr("max X")
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 825
        y: 176
        text: qsTr("Zoom")
        onClicked: {
            if(mintxt.text>maxtxt.text)
                msgbox.open()
            else

                axisX.min=mintxt.text;
                axisX.max=maxtxt.text;
        }
    }







}


Component.onCompleted: {
    var series = chartViewItem.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeSpline,"Random",axisX,axisY)


    chartmodel.get_data()


}
}
```

When I used `chartmodel.generateData()` , the code works with generated data but when I tried the `get_data` function it returns the error below:

> Error: list index out of range

How to update the chart with new data instead of generated data?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the OP is copying code without understanding it, for example is the index necessary? What is the purpose of the index? Surely in the original example the author of the code was trying to show a trivial example showing a cyclic data.

In this case, you have to iterate over the list:

```
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCharts import *
from PySide2.QtQml import *
from time import *
import random


class Thread(QThread):

    motor1 = Signal(int)
    motor2 = Signal(int)
    motor3 = Signal(int)
    var = Signal(int)
    strr = Signal(str)

    def run(self):
        client.connect()

        while True:
            d1 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_1")
            d2 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_2")
            d3 = client.get_node("ns=4;s=Deger_3")
            button = client.get_node("ns=4;s=QT_Button")
            string = client.get_node("ns=4;s=QT_String")
            button = button.get_value()
            string = string.get_value()
            d1 = d1.get_value()
            d2 = d2.get_value()
            d3 = d3.get_value()
            self.motor1.emit(d1)
            self.motor2.emit(d2)
            self.motor3.emit(d3)
            self.var.emit(d1)
            self.strr.emit(string)


class ChartModel(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ChartModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread.var.connect(self.opcua)
        self.thread.start()
        self.timestamp = time()

        self.my_list = []

    @Slot(QtCharts.QAbstractSeries)
    def update_series(self, series):
        series.clear()

        for p in self.my_list:
            series.append(p.x(), p.y())

    @Slot(int)
    def opcua(self, val):
        tsignal = time() - self.timestamp
        XY = QPoint(tsignal, val)
        self.my_list.append(XY)


class MainWindow(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    chartmodel = ChartModel()
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    # engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("backend", main)
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("chartmodel", chartmodel)
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "qml/main.qml"))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtCharts 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.0
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.1


Window {
    width: 1000
    height: 800
    visible: true


    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        property int amountOfData: 0
        color: "#27273a"
        anchors.fill: parent
        Timer{
            id: miTimer
            interval: 100
            running: true
            repeat: true
            onTriggered: {
                chartmodel.update_series(chartViewItem.series(0))
            }
        }
        MessageDialog {
            id: msgbox
            title: "Error"
            text: "Data are not accepted !"
            onAccepted: {
                msgbox.close();


            }
            Component.onCompleted: visible = false
        }

        ChartView {
            id: chartViewItem
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 752
            height: 592
            antialiasing: true
            theme:ChartView.ChartThemeDark
            ValueAxis {
                id: axisX
                min:0
                max:500

            }

            ValueAxis{
                id: axisY
                min:0
                max:100
            }

            Rectangle {
                id: horizontalScrollMask
                visible: false
                anchors.fill: parent
            }

            MouseArea {
                id: chartMouseAreaA
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.rightMargin: -8
                anchors.bottomMargin: -8
                anchors.leftMargin: 8
                anchors.topMargin: 8

                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton | Qt.RightButton

                onMouseXChanged: {
                    if ((mouse.buttons & Qt.LeftButton) == Qt.LeftButton) {
                        chartViewItem.scrollLeft(mouseX - horizontalScrollMask.x);


                        horizontalScrollMask.x = mouseX;
                    }
                }
                onPressed: {
                    if (mouse.button == Qt.LeftButton) {
                        horizontalScrollMask.x = mouseX;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        TextField {
            id: mintxt
            x: 766
            y: 68
            placeholderText: qsTr("min X")
        }

        TextField {
            id: maxtxt
            x: 766
            y: 124
            placeholderText: qsTr("max X")
        }

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 825
            y: 176
            text: qsTr("Zoom")
            onClicked: {
                if(mintxt.text>maxtxt.text)
                    msgbox.open()
                else

                    axisX.min=mintxt.text;
                axisX.max=maxtxt.text;
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var series = chartViewItem.createSeries(ChartView.SeriesTypeSpline,"Random",axisX,axisY)
        miTimer.start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, how to make X axis max and min values scroll based on recieved data?

Comment: @user31562 If you have another question then create another post (please be detailed), those are the site rules.